# regular expressions: OR (|) in subpattern not working

Tags: php, regex

I have two cases to match: either

```
# ... ([0-9]+,[0-9]+)&nbsp;&euro; ... #
```

or

```
# ... (--) ... #
```

Now,

```
# ... (?:(--)|([0-9]+,[0-9]+)&nbsp;&euro;) ... #
```

isn't working, it says

```
Unknown modifier '(' ...
```

I'm using preg_match_all() on PHP 5.3

Those above are NOT the full expressions, just extracts!

Comment: Can you post how you've defined your pattern in a PHP context?

Comment: If these are just extract, please provide the entire regular expressions as the ones you post work without errors...

Comment: I believe the use of pipe character in regular expression is referred to as "alternation" rather than "OR".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regular expression works without errors:

```
 $p = "/(?:(--)|([0-9]+,[0-9]+)&nbsp;&euro;)/";
 echo preg_match($p, "--")."\n";                // outputs 1
 echo preg_match($p, "nomatch")."\n";           // outputs 0
```

Please post your PHP code so we can identigy the problem

Comment: the code is a little too complex, for it builds the complete expression in loops and so on. 
But I found the bug, I was using | as delimiters, what I completely fogot.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the plain regular expressions in delimiters to get a [regular expression in PCRE format](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.pcre.php), for example with `/` as delimiter:

```
/(?:(--)|([0-9]+,[0-9]+)&nbsp;&euro;)/
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you put the delimiters?

```
preg_match_all('#(?:(--)|([0-9]+,[0-9]+)&nbsp;&euro;)#', ...)
```

instead of

```
preg_match_all('(?:(--)|([0-9]+,[0-9]+)&nbsp;&euro;)', ...)
```